# How can I get an external program to change values inside the Arduino C++ code?

Tags: arduino-uno, arduino-ide, c++

How can I get some constantly changing values from a separate C++ program entered and uploaded into the Arduino?

I notice when I upload code to the Arduino in the IDE it takes about a second to start moving. This is also a problem. I would like there to be no delay after instructions to the motor change.
My goal is to get a trained neural network model from the PyTorch C++ version to control the motor's spin and speed. I would assume the IDE does not allow one to import PyTorch?

I tried looking around on the Arduino website for this, but it seems like the IDE is the only option. My solution would be something that imports the Arduino library into a C++ program just like I import the PyTorch library into my C++ program.

My ficticous C++ code. Just written to illustrate what I would like to happen.

```
import pytorch
import arduino

// if I had an encoder on the motor giving position readings as inputs (I know this isn't how it's done in real code)
sensors = arduino_encoder_sensors

// trained model
m = pytorch.load_torch_model('model')

// model taking sensors as inputs and outputting desired speed and distance executions to the motor
speed, dist = m(sensors)
```

**Arduino Code:**

```
const int stepPin = 8; 
const int dirPin = 9; 
 
void setup() {
  // Sets the two pins as Outputs
  pinMode(stepPin,OUTPUT); 
  pinMode(dirPin,OUTPUT);
}
  digitalWrite(dirPin,HIGH); // Enables the motor to move in a particular direction
  for(int x = 0; x < dist; x++) {
    digitalWrite(stepPin,HIGH); 
    delayMicroseconds(speed); 
    digitalWrite(stepPin,LOW); 
  delay(1000); // One second delay
}
```

Comment: the Arduino sketch runs on the Arduino, you can send values to the Arduino over serial port

Comment: Thank you. I'm looking around for this option. Any examples what code into the serial port looks like? Is it something I can send out of any C++ program? I can't picture how this works. Not the USB, but a serial port?

Comment: your fictitious code has no I/O to another device ... it also has a 1 second delay, during which the arduino is doing nothing ... see blinkWithoutDelay example sketch

Comment: It sounds like self modifying code, that will not work, it takes a lot of time. Why not set up a communication link so they can talk to each other. You can use CAN, Ethernet or something else depending on how much data and how fast it has to be transfered. RS485 will work with the serial port in the Arduino. Remember if the processor only has one USART that will also have to be used for uploading code etc.  The data can be saved in RAM. You can use software serial or another Arduino that has more than one port.

Comment: It's difficult to understand what you're asking. An Arduino program is just C++ code; if a library is compatible you can import it. Arduinos can also be very resource-constrained, so the *type* of Arduino is important to know. Any editor/IDE with some form of Arduino support can be used (e.g., I use the Arduino IDE, VS Code, and CLion).

Comment: Is it a copy and paste error, that you don't have a `loop()` function? Currently your code isn't compilable. And are you missing a closing bracket for the for loop? Currently the delay is inside the for loop, but I think you mean it to be outside.

Comment: What values?  Both ways?  From arduino -> otherComputer and from otherComputer -> Arduino?

Answer (score 2):

Your question seems very confused, so I will try to shine a light on some basic distinctions.

> How can I get some constantly changing values from a separate C++ program entered and uploaded into the Arduino?

In your whole question you seem to confuse program and data. The program on the Arduino doesn't need to change with every changing of the values. Instead you would have a constant program, which receives changing values from the PC.

So it seems you want to send data from your python program on your PC to the Arduino. This data doesn't have anything to do with the actual program on the Arduino. The program just should use the data to act accordingly. You can use any of the communication interfaces that are usable with Arduinos and PCs, though the simplest option would be the `Serial` interface, which gets bridged to your PC via the USB port. The `Serial` interface is what you see in the Serial Monitor.

How to use a serial port in python can be googled quite easily. For the Arduino side there are many tutorials and examples about it online. You would also need to think about your communication protocol, which you want to impose on the `Serial` byte stream. For example you could use ASCII encoded text, each message delimited to the next by a newline character `'\n'`, each message containing first the command and then needed parameters. Since only you know what exactly you want to send to the Arduino, you need to design this yourself.

> I notice when I upload code to the Arduino in the IDE it takes about a second to start moving. This is also a problem.

This is due to the bootloader. When you upload a program this is done via the `Serial` interface. Normally microcontrollers can only be programmed over specialized interfaces (like ISP). But Arduinos (and other microcontrollers) can be programmed with a bootloader. That is a program sitting on the microcontroller, which runs anytime you power the microcontroller on your reset it. On Arduinos it will listen on the `Serial` port for a moment in the case that you want to upload a new code. If yes, then it handle the communication and write the new code to the Arduinos flash memory. If not, it will execute whatever program currently is saved in flash.

So you cannot avoid this delay without changing or deleting the bootloader. Deleting it would mean that you need a programmer board to upload new code (another Arduino can do that). Changing it would also require a programmer board, because you would need to write the new bootloader version to the Arduino with it.

I would debate if this delay is really a problem. It only appears on a reset, like when you upload new code. And why would you want to reset the Arduino or upload new codes that fast? For doing your motor movement you don't need new programs on the Arduino for every movement; you need a code that will move according to data send through the `Serial` interface. And that doesn't require resetting. And it works fast.

That said, with your current code (ignoring the obvious syntax problems most likely from copy and past errors) you will still have delays, even when you implement `Serial` communication. In general you shouldn't use long `delay()` calls. You use `delay(1000)`, which makes the Arduino twiddle its thumbs for one whole second each loop iteration. Instead use the non-blocking coding style shown in the `BlinkWithoutDelay` example that comes with the Arduino IDE. It uses the `millis()` function as a clock, checking it regularily for the time to do something. There are many tutorials about that online.

> My goal is to get a trained neural network model from the PyTorch C++ version to control the motor's spin and speed. I would assume the IDE does not allow one to import PyTorch?

No, it doesn't. It is based on Java, not on python. As described above you need to write your own python program and use a fitting serial port python module for the communication over the `Serial` interface. In that python program you can import `PyTorch`, do your  neural network processing and then send the resulting commands over `Serial` to the Arduino.

> I tried looking around on the Arduino website for this, but it seems like the IDE is the only option. My solution would be something that imports the Arduino library into a C++ program just like I import the PyTorch library into my C++ program.

It is not really clear what you mean here. For communicating with an Arduino over `Serial` you can use any program that can interface with a serial port on your PC. There are many programs dedicated for this. Since you want to do your neural networking stuff in python, just use a fitting python module that handles serial port connections.

If you talk about writing programs for Arduinos and uploading them: This can be done in many other IDEs other than the Arduino IDE. Dave Newton mentioned some in his comment: VS Code and CLion. I also remember the Atom IDE. Or you can write your code in any text editor of your liking and then compile and upload the code with the Arduino CLI tool (that's what I do mostly).

---

I hope this clears up the confusion a bit so that you now can work toward a working solution.

Comment: I want to import PyTorch and a saved model into the Arduino IDE. I didn't know if this was possible, but I'm working on figuring out if that is possible now. If I can't import PyTorch and the model into the IDE then I need the Arduino library and ability to 'upload' code to the Arduino device in some other way that I am not yet aware of. This is what I am asking. I'd appreciate an upvote on my question. I don't see any part of it as confused. I'm not being snarky when I say that. I am NOT going to be using Python. If someone would just suggest a method other than the IDE I would give them a gr

Comment: @Ant But if you don't want to use python, why do you want to import PyTorch, which is a python library? And you definitely **cannot** import PyTorch in the Arduino IDE or an Arduino program. Just completely different frameworks. There might be C++ libraries for neural networks which are Arduino compatible, but then the Uno is most likely a bad choice, since it has so few RAM and processing power. Does the model fit in 2KB RAM? I think there are microcontroller boards dedicated to AI stuff with way more RAM and processing power (most likely not directly by Arduino but Arduino compatible).

Comment: PyTorch is available in a C++ version. I am using PyTorch in C++

Comment: Ah, ok, must have overread that. Sure, you can include any C++ libraries in your code that you like. You will need to place these libraries either in the libraries folder or in the same folder as the sketch so that the Arduino IDE finds them. Though I don't know of they are compatible or usable with Arduinos. You can try it. I would guess that you run into memory problems on the Uno. Also have a lookout for dynamic memory allocation, which is often really bad on microcontrollers due to memory fragmentation. Tomorrow I eill change my answer to fit better

Comment: Dave Newton answered that I could import any C++ library. I didn't realize the IDE was flexible enough to do that. Since he said that I have been trying to install the C++ version of PyTorch. It's taking me hours to get it installed with the right CUDA version and getting Pytorch 'built' after the install. The answer to my OP is to launch Arduino in an env with Libtorch installed and put `#include <torch/torch.h>` in the IDE. I think. Should work, I'm told here.

Comment: I was thinking about memory earlier today. Yes, I might need a custom upgrade!